# Is it somehow possible to get session ip when downloading file?

Tags: ip, cdn

I want to get ip address of downloading file. If i making ping to file url, it always showing the same ip, no matter where you are. Maybe when you downloading a file, the session ip is another? How to check it?
Thanks!

Comment: Session's IP depends on the user's connection, which should vary depending on their location unless they're using a VPN/proxy, or your server masks the client's IP. Can you clarify and give an example of what you're getting right now?

Comment: I want to get session ip address when getting file from cdn. This file: https://c7702dad-9281-4c9b-b3d3-544c4e1e3ee6.selcdn.net/200MB.zip I suppose that ip from ping file and session ip when you downloading a file Will be different. My aim is to resolve the real address where this file from cdn located.

Comment: Since Selectel DNS rely on anycast, I'd bet their CDN service also rely on anycast. With anycast, the IP remain the same wherever you are, but the BGP routing ensure each client are served by local node.